# Am I right to believe that this sentence is a complete mess. (And why?)

Tags: meaning, false-friend

tl;dr: Can you confirm the text below is a total shitshow:

> You will be responsible for all international groups coming to Sydney and to create an excellent welcoming attitude through Syntex corporate headquarter in planning and executing international visits. The international guest relation coordinator is part of the global education team to assist the preparation of programs and meetings offered by international education as well as visiting journalist, bloggers, influencer, new customers and distributors.

So I have little to none formal education in English. I speak and read it on daily basis but whenever I have to be a little bit more formal and concise i struggle, mainly because I rely on my feeling whether or not something "sounds right" quite alot. Me and a friend stumbled over this job offer:

I told my friend that I thought this sentence was a complete mess but he argued it was good english. Considering the fact that I have relatively little formal English education I couldn't come up with anything other than my feeling that something was "off" to substantiate my claims.

I have given up on trying to analyze the sentence structure and grammar my formal education is just way to bad.  Truth be told I don't know what words like "substantive", "conjugation", "object" etc. even mean. So If someone could just confirm that this sentence is a complete mess (and maybe even provide some insight on why it is)  so I can get back my piece of mind that my intuition isn't completely off, that would be highly appreciated.

The part that rips me up the most is this:

> to create an excellent welcoming attitude through Syntex corporate headquarter in planning and executing international visits.

If i understand the sentence correctly *welcoming* is an adjective here so 
it would have to be either

> to create an excellent and welcoming attitude

or atleast something that is valid especially in spoken english but feels odd in writing

> to create an excellent, welcoming attitude

It's hard to put in words but whitout an emphasis on the first part of *welcoming* which can't be conveyed in writing to me it feels blunt and clumsy to just list adjectives like that.

Also is *attitude* really something you can *create* rather *forming* or *developing* it?

I'm familiar with the expession of

> doing something through something else

i'm really confused by

> doing something through something else in doing something else

though like I said my formal understanding of english is to bad but I can definetly say that:

> to create an excellent welcoming attitude through Syntex corporate headquarter *in* planning and executing international visits

using *in* is inherently harder for me to understand than *using*

> to create an excellent welcoming attitude through Syntex corporate headquarter *by* planning and executing international visits

Can you actually say *i created something in planing and executing international visits*  rather than *i created something by planning and executing*

Why is *relation* singular?

> guest relation coordinater

Unless you see the guests as a single entity and you have a single relation to this entity rather than multiple relations to the members of the entity it doesn't make sense and should be *relations* instead.

> headquarter

Doesn't exist in singular form as far as i know and is always used with an 's' at the end.

Comment: Did you intend to quote some other text, because the words substantive", "conjugation" and "object" you are confused about the, are not in that quote? In the quote there is "global education team" and later in the sentence, there is: "offered by international education" - it seams that "team" is missing there. The use of both global and international is also confusing - it's not clear if these are two teams or only one.

Comment: Recruiting copy is not proofread (much or at all) or subject to style guides that reputable newspapers are. If you want to analyse English, start with good English from reputable sources. Anyone can write bad English and analysing it is not useful.

Comment: @CJ Dennis You're right that analyzing grammatical English is better and more productive for new learners. Yet, there is *some* use in studying "bad English" or ungrammatical sentences. Through examining the occasional ungrammatical sentence, we can learn about the grammar rules from another p.o.v., which may help folks who're struggling. Sometimes you must learn about "the wrong" in order to understand "the right".  Secondly, understanding difference in academic/recruiting copy vs colloquial speech is useful for new learners, giving them breadth to the trends in English grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instinct of whether something "sounds right" is a good one. From my experience (Bachelor's degree in English), when sentences "don't sound right," it is usually for two reasons.

(1) the grammar in the sentence is not commonly used (idiomatic), and/or

(2) that the grammar and structure of the sentence is extra complicated.

In this situation, you and your friend are both right.

In the quoted segment you provide, that type of sentence structure is **not colloquial**. "Colloquial" describes the way people communicate casually, typically in verbal conversation. So in that sense, the quoted text seems very strange.

However, the sentences in the quote structure are **somewhat typical** in an academic or professional context. Academic and other professional writing styles often use longer, more grammatically complex sentences. They tend to do this, because the content of their writing focuses on combining a lot of ideas and analyzing them all at once. They also use more complex words and grammar to be more precise. This happens in the quote you provide. So, in a sense, the quote is good English. It is functional and, with a lot of extra effort, can be understood.

However, your instincts are revealing something else that's important! Number two of my list -- that the grammar is extra complicated. Just because academics **can** use overly complex sentences, doesn't mean they should. And in fact, using complicated sentences sometimes makes them harder to understand! When a writer uses complex grammar to make a sentence seem more important than it is, that shows that the writer isn't actually that good. The phrase "Short and sweet" comes to mind as a good counter-argument to the long complex sentences.

Also the quoted text is only two sentences! And I bet the rest of that job offer is structured similarly. That is a lot of information to pack into only two sentences. The writer of that job offer would have done better to break those two sentences into at least 3-4.

---

## About "welcoming"

So adjectives in English are quirky. English has a very specific order that adjectives are "right" or "grammatical" in. I have [a link to a cute tumblr picture post](https://oceaxe-ifdawn.tumblr.com/post/169833637581/windycityteacher-burntcopper-things-english) about it and [another article here](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/adjectives/order-of-adjectives/).

> adjectives in English absolutely have to be in this order: opinion-size-age-shape-colour-origin-material-purpose Noun. So you can have a lovely little old rectangular green French silver whittling knife. But if you mess with that word order in the slightest you'll sound like a maniac.

In the case of "welcoming," part of why it's weird is that the writer is using two adjectives -- "welcoming" and "excellent" -- from the "opinion" or "quality" category. The writer could have used only "welcoming" in the job offer, but added "excellent" because the job offer wants to target the highest quality workers. It's clumsy to use more than one adjective in the job offer. It's good to note that when we list adjectives, we **do need** some way to connect them -- either through the addition of "and," or through adding commas, which indicate a pause and that a connection is made in the text.

Both your examples

> to create an excellent and welcoming attitude
>   to create an excellent, welcoming attitude

are grammatical and accurate. The writer of the job offer should have picked one to use, which would have made the language clearer.

## About "attitude"

To my knowledge, all of those

> she created a good attitude at work
>   she formed a good attitude after work
>   she developed a good attitude at work

all make sense, though all sound very formal. More common (and idiomatic) is using the verb "to have," as in:

> she has a good attitude at work
>   she had a bad mood before work

For this, it might come down to how the English language structures ideas about opinions and moods, and emotions that people have. Note, I am **not** referring to "grammatical mood" right now, which is something different. In English, for example, moods and opinions are something we have, that we possess inherently. We also use the verb "to be" for moods and emotions.

> she is sad
>   she is in a bad mood

But interestingly, it would be ungrammatical to say:

> she is good attitude [ungrammatical]

Because of how the English language structures thought, attitudes are something we have. Attitudes can also be something we make or change, but they seem to be something that changes infrequently, so it is something we "have".

## About "doing something"

This problem seems related to [prepositions](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/preposition/) to me, but I take a while to get to the point. So we've got:

> (1) doing something through something else
>   (2) doing something through something else in doing something else

In (1), the relationship between "something" and "something else" is a relationship of cause and effect, **or** of noticing an effect and the place the effect occurs in.

So, "...[an excellent welcoming attitude] **through** [Syntex corporate headquarter]..."

[an excellent welcoming attitude] is the effect and,
[Syntex corporate headquarter] is where the effect takes place.

But what causes the effect in the first place? Well, "the international guest relation coordinator" does.

But how does the coordinator cause the effect?

That is demonstrated in (2): [an excellent welcoming attitude] **through** [Syntex corporate headquarter] **in** [planning and executing international visits].

[planning and executing international visits] is the cause,
and the effect is [an excellent welcoming attitude],
which occurs in [Syntax corporate headquarter]

**Rephrased short and sweet:** The coordinator plans something. The coordinator executes something. The plan and the execution cause "an excellent welcoming attitude". The "excellent welcoming attitude" occurs in "Syntax corporate headquarter".

So the original sentence, with my bold :

> You will be responsible for all international groups coming to Sydney and to create an *excellent welcoming attitude* **through** Syntex corporate headquarter **in** planning and executing international visits.

Much of the complication with "doing something through something else" is **that the wrong prepositions are being used**. The whole sentence would make more sense if we switched the bold prepositions. That leads to this example:

> You will be responsible for all international groups coming to Sydney and to create *an excellent welcoming attitude* **in** Syntex corporate headquarter **through** planning and executing international visits.

In my example, **through** is serving the same purpose as **by** in your example above. Both prepositions indicate that there is a "cause and effect" relationship being described.

## About singular vs plural

To quote the the original quote:

> The international guest relation coordinator is part of the global education team to assist the preparation of programs and meetings

For why "relation" is singular... my best guess is that the writer of the job offer was intending "international guest relation coordinator" to be the whole job title. Since the job title would only be for one person, and only about one person, that is why "relation" was made singular.

In Merriam-Webster dictionary, "[relation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relation)" is actually a singular noun for entries 1-5 in the definition. In entries 6 and 7, it is listed as the plural "relations" with a slightly different meaning and connotation.

Grammatically, both "relation" and "relations" are acceptable here. The difference between them is small; both singular and plural forms indicate that the job of the coordinator is focused on the connections between multiple guests, and connections between guests and non-guests.

Using the word "relation" has an implication that the coordinator acts and speaks with the guests (probably to meet their needs).

If "relations" is used, it would imply more focus on the connections between guests, the guests interactions with each other, and the guests interactions with others. There is slightly less emphasis on the coordinators individual role...the coordinator is more of a mediator between others.

> headquarter

As for "headquarter" you are right that it doesn't typically exist as singular. It should be "headquarters" instead. I would guess that this is a typo, but it's also very possible the writer doesn't know this exception to the usual singular/plural rules in English.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer, is it perhaps possible that the author of the job listing isn't exactly well versed in this more sophisticated writing style either and therefore, even though the sentences are technically correct, they aren't as coherent and on-point as they could be? I read scientific publications in English from time to time but I rarely ever get the same feeling of reading prolonged sentences that  just feel like nonsensical gibberish glued together to sound weighty.

Comment: @xtr You're welcome! It's very possible the job poster is not familiar with the writing style, and it could be in a couple different ways. The job poster may not have experience organizing their writing in general, or with this specific topic. They may be unfamiliar with how to structure complex sentences, so that the same topics are linked. In contrast, scientific publications are typically reviewed by others in the same field, and even by people associated with the publisher. So, scientific publications are usually written (and reviewed) to be clear and well organized.